# Submit Form on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

How can I submit a form on an image click? The form does not get submitted with the code below. Is there a way to do this without jQuery?

**Razor**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignLabels", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "AssignLabelsForm" }))
{
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Labels.png") />
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').on("click", function () {
    $(this).submit();
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AssignLabels()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect an **image** to do when you call submit on it?

Comment: and the down votes are for...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('img').on("click", function () {
    $('#AssignLabelsForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use image button

```
<input type="image" src="Your source of image" alt="Form submit image" />
```

for more information, refer here https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1

Answer (score -1):

In your code, the $(this) refers to the image element...specify submitting the form specifically:

```
$('img').on("click", function () {
    $(form).submit();
});
```